# Stop fetching GPS location if application goes in background in ANDROID

Tags: android, gps

I am currently working on a task where i need to fetch the locations from GPS.
The concern i am having here is that once i obtain the location & the task goes completed, after this if the application goes in background i do not wish to obtain any locations until & unless my application is back on screen (foreground) whatis currently not happening. (kindly note here i am not talking about switching the activity from one to another via intent as my app has only one screen & one activity).

I wish to know what place exactly the code to handle this situation must go & how can i do achieve this. I have tried with setting the instance to null & remove update but it proves ineffective. May be i am putting it at wrong place i am putiing it outside `onCreate()` inside the class extending activity.

Comment: call this "location_manager.removeUpdates(locationListener);" in activity onPause().

Comment: @llango thanks fro replying. i appreciate your quick response, i am testing with this now & if worked will definitely let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `requestForLocationUpdates()` in `onResume()`

and `removeUpdates()` in `onPause()`

> Once I obtain the location & the task goes completed

If you just want one Lat, Lon fix: don't use the tracking mode, instead use : [requestSingleUpdate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29)

Comment: Thanks fro replying. i appreciate your quick response, Howver the concern to fetch multiple locations is this that i have a button which gets enabled only after receiving GPS, so if the applications remains in foreground & user had moved then the new GPS position must be provide & hence i am fetching locations again but that too i want it in foreground only. i am testing with this now & if worked will definitely let you know.